# Why does this code results in an segmentation fault error?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am building this with cmake, using gcc on ubuntu 19.04
When I run this, it results in an segmentation fault exception inside the list_dir function.
I have no idea why.
Please help.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

static void list_dir(const std::string &path, bool recursive){

    try{
        std::vector<std::string> dirs;

        try{
            for (const auto &entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)){
                std::cout << entry << "\n";     

                if(recursive && entry.is_directory() && !entry.is_symlink())
                    dirs.push_back(entry.path().string());
            }
        }
        catch(const fs::filesystem_error &err){
            std::cerr << "err: " << err.what() << "\n";
        }

        if(recursive){
            for (const auto &p : dirs)
                list_dir(p, true);
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception &err){
        std::cerr << "err: " << err.what() << "\n";
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: index <dir>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    list_dir(argv[1], true);
    std::cout << "Done.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Update: The exception happens on this line of code

```
for (const auto &entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
```

Update: In case someone interested, here is the cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
project(index VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) 
file(GLOB_RECURSE SourceFiles "src/*.cpp" "src/*.h")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SourceFiles})
```

Comment: try to catch not the references but copy the exception.

Comment: @arsdever Just tried, same result.

Comment: segmentation fault happens when your program access a memory location that it is not supposed to. 
Are there any pointers going around poking at address that they shouldn't?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Does it break on a specific file/directory?

Comment: @Anuvrat Parashar well, that's all the code there are, nothing else.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it breaks when it first enter the for loop, at this line:
for (const auto &entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))

Comment: Does your directory structure contain any cycles? This would create an infinite recursion, but would probably end with a stack overflow. Have you tried with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator?

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason you didn't dual-branch this to use `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` in the recursive case and let the iterator do the heavy-lifting? Just wondering.

Comment: @Marko Mahnič When I build and run that example code on my machine, I got the same error, I am so suprised!!!

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem, I didn't link against the filesystem library, which was causing the error, although I have no idea why the code can still be compiled without the proper linking libraries...

In cmake, after I added:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "-lstdc++fs")
```

Everything works fine now.